# Creating a GROUP via Users & Groups in command line

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'd like to script the action of creating a group via Users & Groups and binding it to the admin account *and* enabling remote login for the same group enabled service and support.

I'm vaguely familiar with commands like dscl - but I'm not sure if this is even the right command

I've seen sudo dscl localhost -append /Local/Default/Groups/thegroupname GroupMembership theusername - to add an admin user to a group  BUT  What should be put for GroupMembership - if this command is correct   - The name of my group is Service and Support

Answer (score 17):

To create a group, add some users and enabling remote login for the same group **from scratch** do the following:

Locally:

Create group:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/servsupport
```

Add some details like real name, password etc.:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/servsupport RealName "Service and Support"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/servsupport passwd "*"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/servsupport gid 799
```

Use an unused groupID number as gid! You get a sorted list of used gids by entering:

```
dscl . list /Groups PrimaryGroupID | tr -s ' ' | sort -n -t ' ' -k2,2
```

There is also an answer somewhere at apple.stackexchange.com how to find the first free uid or gid *greater than x* and how to apply it to new groups or users.

Add an admin user (here I assume the user name is *admin*):

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/servsupport GroupMembership admin
```

If you want to add a second user use the subcommand `append`:

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/servsupport GroupMembership admin2
```

Test whether the group *SSH Service ACL* exists:

```
dscl . list /Groups PrimaryGroupID  | grep com.apple.access_ssh*
```

If the group doesn't exist create it similar as the Service and Support group:

```
sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh
sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh RealName "SSH Service ACL"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh passwd "*"
sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh gid 399
```

Add the group *servsupport* as nested group to the SSH Service ACL group if the SSH ACL is already enabled:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a servsupport -t group com.apple.access_ssh
```

or if SSH ACL are dsiabled:

```
sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a servsupport -t group com.apple.access_ssh-disabled
```

Enable remote login:

```
sudo systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

A script doing essentially this except creating a new Service and Support group is available here: [add_localadmins_to_ssh](https://gist.github.com/pmbuko/5415282). The linked script requires slight mods to meet your requirements.

---

Based on the linked script I made a new one meeting your requirements. Take it with a grain of salt and test it thoroughly:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set the input for lazy convenience
IFS=$' '

# We first need to test if the access_ssh group exists and create it if it doesn't

/usr/bin/dscl . list /Groups PrimaryGroupID  | grep com.apple.access_ssh* >  /dev/null 2>&1
rc=$?
if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
    /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh
    /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh RealName "SSH Service ACL"
    /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh passwd "*"
    /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh gid 399
fi

# create  "Service and Support" group and add admin users

localadmins=$(/usr/bin/dscl . read /Groups/admin GroupMembership | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')

for account in `echo $localadmins`; do
    # add additional blocks like >> && ! [ "$account" == "username" ] << for additional exclusions
    if ! [ "$account" == "root" ] && ! [ "$account" == "itstech" ]; then
        userID=$(/usr/bin/dscl . read /Users/$account | grep GeneratedUID | awk '{print $2}')
        if [ "$userID" != "" ]; then
            # Test if the servsupport group exists and create it if it doesn't
            /usr/bin/dscl . read /Groups/servsupport > /dev/null 2>&1
            sc=$?
            if [[ $sc != 0 ]]; then
                /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/servsupport
                /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/servsupport RealName "Service and Support"
                /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/servsupport passwd "*"
                /usr/bin/dscl . create /Groups/servsupport gid 799
            fi
            /usr/bin/dscl . append /Groups/servsupport GroupMembership "$userID"
        else
            echo "$account has no local GUID"
        fi
    fi
done

# Add the "Service and Support" group as nested group to the SSH Service ACL group depending on the state of SSH Service ACL.

GroupState=$(/usr/bin/dscl . list /Groups RealName | grep "SSH Service ACL" | awk '{print $1}')
dseditgroup -o edit -a servsupport -t group $GroupState

if ! [ "$GroupState" == "com.apple.access_ssh" ]; then
    /usr/bin/dscl . change /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh-disabled RecordName com.apple.access_ssh-disabled com.apple.access_ssh
fi

# Enable Remote Login service

systemsetup -setremotelogin on
```

---

In a managed environment (OpenDirectory or AD) with OD/AD users/groups with local admin access permissions it's much simpler.

---

If you've already created the group you can lookup the groupID and the group name (`servsupport` above) by right-clicking the group name in "Users & Groups".

Comment: This is a very cool and insightful post, huge thanks

Comment: `sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh gid 399` didn't work for me, but `sudo dscl . create /Groups/com.apple.access_ssh PrimaryGroupID 399` did

Comment: @screamingdrills What's your system version (e.g. 10.15)?

Comment: I tried it on High Sierra